# Zoom in and zoom out for R graph

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, iplots

I know the question was already asked, but i couldn't solve my problem.
I get a graph unreadale when i choose the text argument for my graph and when i choose the identify argument it's not better.[image]

This is what i get whith this script :

```
VehiculeFunction <- function(data, gamme, absciss, ordinate, label, xlim, ylim){
  my.data <- data[data$GAMME == gamme,]
  ma.col = rgb(red = 0.1,blue = 1,green = 0.1, alpha = 0.2)
  X <- my.data[[absciss]] 
  Y <- my.data[[ordinate]] 
  Z <- my.data[[label]]
  X11()
  plot(X, Y, pch=20, las = 1, col = ma.col, xlab = absciss, ylab = ordinate, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
  text(X, Y, labels = Z, pos=3, cex = 0.7, col = ma.col)
  #identify(X, Y, labels = Z, cex = 0.7)
}

VehiculeFunction(data.vehicule, "I", "GMF.24", "Cout.24", "NITG", c(0,0.2), c(0,0.2))
```

I used iplot, but i couldn't add the identify and text argument...
I never used ggplot, so i don't know if it's could solve my problem.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Do you expect the labels to be legible if you label all of those points? Or are labels only shown on mouseover? (Also, I'm not sure how the question title reflects the question content)

Comment: I know this is illegible for this scale but if i could zoom it will be possible to see all the points i want ?

Comment: Even with the identify argument, it's illigible if i had too many points. What i want is to adjust xlim and ylim with the mouse ? is-it possible with a package ?

Comment: Maybe you wanna export the plot into a really large png or svg

Comment: I don't thik it's going to work, i have around 1500 dots after filtrate it!

Comment: googleVis could do what i want ? if someone used it ?

Answer (score 2):

A tool that might help with is `facet_zoom` from the [`ggforce`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ggforce) package.

I don't have access to the `data.vehicule` object,  so I will use the `mtcars` `data.frame` for an example of zooming in on a region of the graphic.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(dplyr)

mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% mutate(nm = rownames(mtcars))

ggplot(mtcars2) +
  aes(x = wt, y = mpg, label = nm) +
  geom_text()

last_plot() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_zoom(x = dplyr::between(wt, 3, 4),
             y = dplyr::between(mpg, 12, 17))
```

[image]